# Looping over brackets with regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

Regex extracting 99% of desired result.

This is my line:

> Customer Service Representative (CS) (TM PM *) **

1. *Can have more parameters. Example (TM PM TR) etc
2. **Can have more parenthesis. Example (TM PM) (RI) (AB CD) etc

Except for the first bracket `(CS in this case)` which is group 1, I can have any number of parenthesis and any number of parameters within those parenthesis in group 2.

My attempt yields the desired result, but with brackets

```
(\(.*?\))\s*(\(.*?\).*)
```

My result:

[image]

My desired result:

```
group 1 : CS
group 2 : if gg yiy rt jfjfj jhfjh uigtu
```

I want help on removing those parenthesis from the result.

My attempt:

`\((.*?)\)\s*\((.*?\).*)`

which gives me

[image]

Can someone help me with this? I need to remove all the brackets from group 2 as well. I have been at it for a long time but can't figure out a way. Thank you.

Comment: You can't match disjoint sections of text using a single match operation. When you need to repeat a group, there is no way to even use a replace approach with capturing groups. You need a second post-process step to remove `(` and `)` from Group 2 value.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I handle the post process step in code?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Yes, you do not have any other option. Some kind of `Group2value = Group2value.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "")` will nail it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: .NET C# mvc

Comment: The code in my above comment is C#, BTW. Add it as a post process step and that is all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't match disjoint sections of text using a single match operation. When you need to repeat a group, there is no way to even use a replace approach with capturing groups.

You need a post-process step to remove `(` and `)` from Group 2 value.

So, after you get your matches with the current approach, remove all `(` and `)` from the Group 2 value with

```
Group2value = Group2value.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach which uses string splitting along with the base string functions:

```
string input = "(CS) (if gg yiy rt) (jfjfj) (jhfjh uigtu)";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, "\\) \\(");
string grp1 = parts[0].Replace("(", "");
parts[0] = "";
parts[parts.Length - 1] = parts[parts.Length - 1].Replace(")", "");
string grp2 = string.Join(" ", parts).Trim();

Console.WriteLine(grp1);
Console.WriteLine(grp2);

CS
if gg yiy rt jfjfj jhfjh uigtu
```

Comment: [Here is a demo](https://rextester.com/PWHW86745) to show that the above script works.